# Is there a way to convert string length as derived from something like strlen() into pixel length in PHP?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

For example:

```
<?php
$string = 'Foo bar';

$length = strlen($string);

echo '<div style="width: '.$length.'px;">'.$string.'</div>';
```

The above obviously does not work, as $length is 7 and 7px is smaller than the size of the outputted text.

I also understand that font size and other factors will come into play, as well.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
<div style="width:xxx; float:left;">Label 1</div><input type="checkbox"/><br/>
<div style="width:xxx; float:left; clear:left;">Longer Label 2</div> <input type="checkbox"/><br/>
<div style="width:xxx; float:left; clear:left;">Even Longer Label 3</div> <input type="checkbox"/><br/>
```

Comment: If you understand, then answer is `$length * $otherFactors`.

Comment: why do you want to do that - if you want the text to fit in the div - just _don't_ give it a width

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: @AD7six for example, say you have checkboxes with corresponding labels. I want the checkboxes to line up based upon the greatest label length.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: @reformed you're describing `display:block` - in short, don't do this - _use css_.

Comment: What I'm looking for is something like this: <div style="width:xxx; float:left;">Label 1</div><input type="checkbox"/><br/>
<div style="width:xxx; float:left; clear:left;">Label 2</div> <input type="checkbox"/><br/>
<div style="width:xxx; float:left; clear:left;">Label 3</div> <input type="checkbox"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the font you'll be using, you want to know about [`imagettfbbox()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php).

But yeah, just dont give widths and right-align the text, or use a grid-system layout like Bootstrap or 960.gs.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your are trying to match the length of the string to the dimensions of the corresponding . As you have already indicated this is only possible if you take Font Type and Size into consideration. Assuming you would have a mono-spaced font you would have to multiply $length with a factor.

The real messy part starts if you use not mono-spaced fonts...

Answer (score 0):

Also if you set value of `display` property to `inline-block` div element behaves like a block element but it's width changes with it's containing elements
`display: inline-block`